# How to make desktop application using html/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Recently,I have seen blue Stack using html to make their Installer, Atom Text Editor their app,etc, So I want to know how this is developed.Because I also want to develop app using it.

Answer (score 0):

May be [cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) can help you to create [windows desktop applications](https://github.com/apache/cordova-windows) using HTML/Javascript

Please let me know if you have any idea about cordova or not. Because I dont want any downvote for my any of answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into  [nw.js](http://nwjs.io)

Its based on node js and can be used for desktop application written in html / css / js.

Answer (score 0):

nw.js (called Node-WebKit before) is a good way to make simple applications, which allows you to use Node.js applications and manipulate the browser's window.

Electron is - I think - a better way because it works as simple as nw.js but permit to make more powerful applications : you can register web protocols, manipulate window in depth, and some things that you can't do with nw.js.